# How to find three unique numbers in a column, stopping, retracking

Tags: unique

I have a column with numbers 1-4 randomly throughout. They may repeat.
I am looking to mark the first time where where 3 of these 4 have occurred.
I then want to ignore one cell (so don't count as part of a set of three).
Then I want to start tracking again looking for the next 3 of the 4 unique values.

The three unique numbers may occur in as little as 3 cells or far more (eg 12121112223.
There is only one number per cell.

Is it possible? I have tried other forums but the variable length of the sequence seems to be a problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it is excel you can use "remove duplicates" under data menu... if it is sql then use  "distinct" keyword

Comment: It is Excel. I don't know how that would help me. Surely that would just remove everything, because the numbers are duplicated throughout the column 1,2,3 and 4 are there multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the occurrence of number 2, then try

```
 =MATCH(2,A:A,0)
```

Similarly you can try

```
  =MATCH(3,A:A,0)
  =MATCH(1,A:A,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I don't. I want to flag when the third if 4 unique values appears in a column, muss a cell and then start tracking again.i have a column of 5000 entries.

Comment: Going to rephrase this for clarity. I want to mark every set of numbers that contain 3 of 4 numbers 1-4. There may be repeats in the column, so the sets could be as small as 3 or more likely bigger.  Additionally, I want to ignore one cell between each set found. So do not include the next cell after the third hit when searching for the next group. The result might be an "x" in the column next to the last of the three numbers to "hit".

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved like this (CSE)
=IF(B1="x","",IF(SUM(1/COUNTIF(INDEX(A$2:A2,IFERROR(MAX(IF(B$1:B1="x",ROW(B$1:B1)))+1,1)):A2,INDEX(A$2:A2,IFERROR(MAX(IF(B$1:B1="x",ROW(B$1:B1)))+1,1)):A2))=3,"x",""))